# Pull out the minumum value in the CSV file

Tags: python, function, csv, program-entry-point, minimum

I am trying to pull out all the relevant info for the lines with the minimum value in a csv file with Python.
Below is my code to find out the relevant information.
The minimum value is 12 when I code it spaerately.
But when I put in the function and will process the minimum to find and record other data in the csv file.The value can not be updated. What I am missing to update the value of line[9]?

The CVS file contains a column of numbers and I need to find the minimum.
The separate coding works well to find the minimum of 12 and I did it as a test. But it does not work after I assign a function and use the same method to find the minimum.
As I need to use the minimum in other part of the code, it is better if I can put it in the function and make it work.
So I would like to know how should transfer the function also works in finding the minimum.
Thank you in advance.

```
#put finding minimum in to a function and will use the returned minimum 
#to pull out other information    
def findMin():  
minMile = 100
if num<minMile:
    minMile=num
return minMile


def main():
    fileIn = open("epaVehicleData2008.csv", "r")
    fileIn.readline()
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.split(",")
        num=int(line[9])
        findmin(line)
        minMile=int(line[9])
        print(minMile)


main()

#separate code for finding the minimum as a test
fileIn = open("epaVehicleData2008.csv", "r")
fileIn.readline()
minMile = 100
for line in fileIn:
    line = line.split(",")
    num = int(line[9])
    if num < minMile:
        minMile = num
print(minMile)
```

Comment: where exactly are you updating the value? all I see you doing is reading the same file twice one time using a function and the other time doing the same exact process without a function, what is the desired output

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Python's CSV library to help with reading each line and automatically splitting it in a list:

```
import csv

def findMin(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        return min(csv_input, key=lambda x: int(x[9]))[9]

print('Min mile', findMin('epaVehicleData2008.csv'))
```

The built-in `min()` function can be used to determine the smallest row. It takes a `key` parameter which tells it which part of the input you want to compare with, in this case the 9th element.

Each time you call your `findMin()`, the value for `minMile` will always be `100`. In your design, you would need to make the variable global, rather than local to your function. Perhaps a better approach would be to pass the function a filename and let it read and calculate the minimum in one go and return that value.

`lambda` is just a function written inline without needing a separate `def`. In this case, it takes `x` being a row, and returns the ninth value as an integer.